# How to set X-Frame-Options header without a custom server in Next.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS app that I need to set `X-Frame-Options` on, but I'm not sure how to do this. With Express, I would use helmetjs, but I want to avoid creating a custom server because:

> Before deciding to use a custom server please keep in mind that it
> should only be used when the integrated router of Next.js can't meet
> your app requirements. A custom server will remove important
> performance optimizations, like serverless functions and Automatic
> Static Optimization.

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

Clearly, there are some drawbacks to using a custom server, and the page handler provided by Next works for me.

Answer (score 9):

Without a custom server, this could be achieved by using [custom headers](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers) in your `next.config.js`.

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/(.*)?', // Matches all pages
                headers: [
                    {
                        key: 'X-Frame-Options',
                        value: 'DENY',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```